# remove spaces and characters from blueimp jqfileupload php

Tags: php, jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I'm using the `jqFileUpload` with the PHP server Upload.
When I upload a file with the name `test-image.jpg` and that file already exists, it renames it to `test-image (1).jpg`.

I would like to change this so it renames to `test-image-1.jpg` or `test-image_1.jpg`

I've looked at the code in `UploadHandler.php` and found the function

```
    protected function upcount_name($name) {
        return preg_replace_callback(
            '/(?:(?: \(([\d]+)\))?(\.[^.]+))?$/',
            array($this, 'upcount_name_callback'),
            $name,
            1
        );
    }
```

I'm just not sure how to make that work for what I want.